# saved model with joblib gives different scores

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, xgboost, joblib

I tuned model with GridSearchCV and I saved it with joblib.

Later on, I load this model and but when I apply the score parameter it gives me different score.

why is this wrong? Shouldn't it be the same? Because X, y doesn't change.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

xgboost  = XGBRegressor()
parameters = {    
                'nthread':[-1], 
                'objective':['reg:squarederror'],
                'learning_rate': [.02, .03, .04], 
                'max_depth': [1,2,5],
                'min_child_weight': [1,2],
                'silent': [1],
                'subsample': [.8,.9],
                'colsample_bytree': [.7,.9],
                'n_estimators': [100,150,200],
}

kf = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=42, shuffle=True)
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgboost, param_grid = parameters, cv = kf, n_jobs=-1, return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error') 
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)

model = gs.best_estimator_.fit(X_train, y_train)
joblib.dump(model, 'model.ml')
gs.score(X,y)
```

It gives : **-0.10654083232458161**

When I load this model

```
model = joblib.load('model.ml')
model.score(X,y)
```

It gives: **0.16716786313061083**